# Error occurred while starting Jetty - javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer in Java11

Tags: java-11, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

Trying to write a simple rest web service using Embedded Jetty server in Java 11. While starting Embedded Jetty server in Java 11 causing this exception.

But same code is working in Java 8

Exception

11:41:18 PM: Executing task ':EmbeddedJettyService.main()'...

> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes

> Task :EmbeddedJettyService.main()
> <<<<< Starting Embedded Jetty Service >>>>>
> Error occurred while starting Jettyjavax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-52aa2946@5a84fc94==org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer,jsp=null,order=0,inst=false

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
11:41:25 PM: Task execution finished ':EmbeddedJettyService.main()'.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
}

repositories {
        jcenter()
}

sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25"
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.25'

    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-server', version: '9.4.9.v20180320'
    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-servlet', version: '9.4.9.v20180320'

    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet-core', version: '2.25.1'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-json-jackson', version: '2.25.1'

    implementation group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-json', version: '1.19.4'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-servlet', version: '1.19.4'

}
```

Main Class:

```
package com.test.main;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;


public class EmbeddedJettyService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startServer();
    }

    public static void startServer() {
        System.out.println("<<<<< Starting Embedded Jetty Service >>>>>");

        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);

        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(servletContextHandler);

        ServletHolder servletHolder =
                servletContextHandler.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/controller/*");
        /* servlet init order - 0 refers init On Startup */
        servletHolder.setInitOrder(0);
        /* servlet init order - 0 refers init On Startup */
        servletHolder.setInitOrder(0);

        servletHolder.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages",
                "com.test.resource");

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred while starting Jetty" +ex);
        }

        finally {
            try {
                server.stop();
                server.destroy();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error during server starting " +e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Resource:

```
package com.test.resource;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@Path("/health")
public class HelloResource {

    @GET
    public String JettyPocResponse() {
        return "Hello from Embedded Jetty!!!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the whole stacktrace for that warning.